# How to parse variable values in stored proc from dataframe using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sqlalchemy, cx-oracle

I have written a code to pick specific values from email body and store it in dataframe now the next step is to store those values in oracle database for that I am using sqlalchemy but I am not sure how I can pass those values to a stored procedure like below

```
call CORE_VALUATIONS.VALUATIONS.INSERTEQCLOSINGPRICE("**SGEPSBSH**",to_date('"&TEXT(**2022-06-01**,"DDMMMYYYY")&"','ddmonyyyy'),"**111.9852**",NULL,NULL);
```

[image]

```
from sqlalchemy.engine import create_engine
import datetime


 today = datetime.date.today()

DIALECT = 'oracle'
SQL_DRIVER = 'cx_oracle'
USERNAME = 'robinhood'  # enter your username
PASSWORD = 'XXXXXX'  # enter your password
HOST = 'pv-prod-orc-01.XXXXX.com'  # enter the oracle db host url
PORT = 1521  # enter the oracle port number
SERVICE = 'XXXX_APP.ec2.internal'  # enter the oracle db service name
ENGINE_PATH_WIN_AUTH = DIALECT + '+' + SQL_DRIVER + '://' + USERNAME + ':' + PASSWORD + '@' + HOST + ':' + str(
    PORT) + '/?service_name=' + SERVICE

engine = create_engine(ENGINE_PATH_WIN_AUTH)

# test query


query = """
call CORE_VALUATIONS.VALUATIONS.INSERTEQCLOSINGPRICE("**SGEPSBSH**",to_date('"&TEXT(**2022-06-01**,"DDMMMYYYY")&"','ddmonyyyy'),"**111.9852**",NULL,NULL);

"""
con = engine.connect()
outpt = con.execute(query)
con.close()
```

Comment: can anyone please help ?

Answer (score 0):

> how can I pass those values to stored procedure

Call `.execute(sql_text, dict_of_param_values)`, e.g., something like

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa

# …

sql_text = sa.text(
    "call CORE_VALUATIONS.VALUATIONS.INSERTEQCLOSINGPRICE(:param1, :param2, :param3, NULL, NULL);"
)
dict_of_param_values = dict(param1="SGEPSBSH", param2="2022-06-01", param3=111.9852)
with engine.begin() as conn:
    conn.execute(sql_text, dict_of_param_values)
# (transaction will automatically commit when `with` block exits)
```